# How to make a javascript section repeat if an alert is canceled?

Tags: javascript, macos, photoshop-script

Apologies if this is a silly question, I'm really new to coding. I have a script that I'm currently running through Photoshop on a Mac, which sorts through images in a folder and saves them to one of several other folders. It works fine, but I have to manually type in the filepaths and re-save the script each time, which is a nuisance.

Instead I want to prompt for the folders at the start, and then give the option to confirm the selection, or start again. The folder prompts are working, but I have no idea how to make the script repeat if the user presses the cancel button.

I've tried searching online for answers, but since I don't really know what I'm looking for I'm not getting very far. My best guess is that maybe I need to use an if/else statement targeting the buttons, or a loop that reiterates until the confirm button is pressed.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true


var sourceFolder = app.chooseFolder({
    withPrompt: "Please select a source folder:"
})

var pathFolder = app.chooseFolder({
    withPrompt: "Please select an output folder for images with correctly named clipping paths:"
})

var unnamedFolder = app.chooseFolder({
    withPrompt: "Please select an output folder for images with unnamed clipping paths:"
})

var noneFolder = app.chooseFolder({
    withPrompt: "Please select an output folder for images with no clipping paths:"
})


var alertText = "Confirm folder locations?"
var alertMessage = "Originals folder: \n" + sourceFolder + "\n\n" + 
    "Path 1 folder: \n" + pathFolder + "\n\n" + 
    "Unnamed Paths folder: \n" + unnamedFolder + "\n\n" + 
    "No Paths folder: \n" + noneFolder
app.displayAlert(alertText, {
    message: alertMessage,
    buttons: ["Change", "Confirm"],
    defaultButton: "Confirm",
    cancelButton: "Change"
})
```

If the "Confirm" button is pressed I want the script to continue on to the next section where it will start sorting the images into the chosen folders. If "Change" is pressed, I want this section of code to start again. How can I make this happen?

Comment: Which version of Photoshop are you using?

Comment: Does `app.displayAlert` have cancel function option?

Comment: I'm confused with the sample code: this isn't Photoshop JS, is this just for reference? It seems that you need to create a ScriptUI window and select all the options on it (more about ScriptUI http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/scriptui.html)

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy this section of the script doesn't need to use any Photoshop functionality, it just sets up the folders that will be used later. My ultimate goal (if I can get there) is to make this into some sort of app that can be run from outside of Photoshop.

Comment: @TedBrownlow I'm using Photoshop CC 2019, but as I mentioned to Sergey this new section of the script doesn't involve Photoshop. I only mentioned it as context, since currently I'm opening the script, changing the file paths, re-saving, then going to Photoshop > File > Scripts > Browse and running it from there. I'd rather turn it into some sort of app that will set up the folders first, then target Photoshop for the image sorting part. Hope this is possible...

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly I'm not sure if I fully understand what you're asking sorry (I'm very much a newbie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have figured it out (thanks Medet Tleukabiluly for mentioning functions, it gave me a new line of exploration):

```
var app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true

var sourceFolder
var pathFolder
var unnamedFolder
var noneFolder

function selectFolders() {
    sourceFolder = app.chooseFolder({
        withPrompt: "Please select a source folder:"
    })
    pathFolder = app.chooseFolder({
        withPrompt: "Please select an output folder for images with correctly named clipping paths:"
    })
    unnamedFolder = app.chooseFolder({
        withPrompt: "Please select an output folder for images with unnamed clipping paths:"
    })
    noneFolder = app.chooseFolder({
        withPrompt: "Please select an output folder for images with no clipping paths:"
    })

    var alertText = "Confirm folder locations?"
    var alertMessage = "Originals folder: \n" + sourceFolder + "\n\n" + 
        "Path 1 folder: \n" + pathFolder + "\n\n" + 
        "Unnamed Paths folder: \n" + unnamedFolder + "\n\n" + 
        "No Paths folder: \n" + noneFolder
    var x = app.displayAlert(alertText, {
        message: alertMessage,
        buttons: ["Change", "Confirm"],
        defaultButton: "Confirm",
    })

    if (x.buttonReturned === "Change") {
        selectFolders()
    }   
}

selectFolders()

app.displayDialog("Confirmed")
```

Not sure if I've done it in the best way possible, but this seems to work - it now repeats the selectFolders function until "Confirm" is pressed, then continues through the script.